# Encoding categorical variable from multiple pandas columns

Tags: python, pandas, encoding, scikit-learn, categorical-data

In a ~1 million row dataset with mostly boolean features, I have 15 columns of string data that I want to encode in a manner that recognizes the interaction between them. So the data is something like this:

```
Name1 Name2 Name3 ...
Jane  John  Julie ...
John  Julie Peter ...
```

The same name can appear in any of the columns, but the names are always within alphabetical order across the columns.
Right now, I reshape the data to "long" format. That allows the machine learning algorithms to recognize that, for example, James is always James regardless of the column he started in, but loses the interaction effects.

```
df = (pd.wide_to_long(df, 
                      stubnames = stubs,
                      i = i,
                      j = j)
        .reset_index())
```

Dummy encoding has a similar problem (and is a bit unwieldy because I have thousands of names).

Leaving it in wide format and encoding each column individually misses that the same person is in different columns (as it is stored in separate categorical variables). So the interaction effects are muted/distorted in that scenario (since James interacting with Julie is different if Anna or Zachary is also with them). What I really want to do is encode the various combinations of names across those columns as a single categorical feature.

For what it's worth, I am also using category_encoders package in the pipeline for other variables and preparing the data primarily for tree (Random Forest) and ensemble (xgboost) methods.

Comment: Concat the three columns into one, and make that a categorical?

Comment: Thanks. There are 15 columns, but I guess I could give that a go because they are always in alphabetical order. That would leave out how, for example, James interacts with different groups of people (since he would become just a substring in a long string). Maybe I could combine the rows with one name left out each time and then change it to long format with the excluded name in a separate column. That will get messy but might work. I appreciate the suggestion.